# Unity3D get progress update from server?

Tags: unity-game-engine

On Server we have an endpoint to finish some task. In Unity3D client side, we want to know the progress of the task. Instead of looping for some status endpoint to get the current status, we are thinking about using websocket. Is there better solution in Unity?

Comment: It depends on the task. What type of task is the client making the server do?

Comment: Thanks for replying, it will do some image processing which takes 10-20 seconds.

Comment: I suggest you use tcp on your server and unity client. This is the right way to go about this

Comment: So that means websocket?

Comment: `TCP != websocket`. Although websocket seems fine.